# How to dynamically load images on scroll without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have gone through multiple forums and tutorials explaining how to dynamically load data.

I understand full well that I need to make an AJAX call to the database via the php file to get the data async.

The images are loaded in a random order at a limit of 12 using a select statement and an order by 
e.g. `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12`

I wish to load more images as the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

The problem is how to ensure that an image isn't loaded twice. I had thought of getting an array of the images that are loaded and passing it with the AJAX call to then perform an appropriate SQL statement to then choose 3 more images "DISTINCT" from the image array and all the images joined.

But I am unsure how to compare an array to an SQL table. Or if this is the best way to tackle the problem.

**Summary:**

Image Table: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16

Images Loaded in HTML: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6

Load 3 more random images distinct from the images loaded in HTML when scrolled to the bottom of the page.

**SIDE NOTE:** I prefer to use pure javascript and not import plug ins.

**EDIT:** I have the logic down, it's more the application of it that I'm struggle with. I should have mentioned that I want to use hash fragments so I can get google to index teh html snapshot which will effectively be all the images loaded.

Comment: use lazyload.... google it

Comment: Try http://dinbror.dk/blazy/

Comment: I do not want to import plug ins! Let me rephrase ... I want to compare an array to an sql statement. I think I have to get the table with all the images, use a union of some sort on the images already loaded in the HTML, then from the new result set select 3 images at random. But I'm not too familiar with SQL anymore to know the exact operations to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save loaded images somewhere (sessions, cookies, javascript) and then use the array of loaded images in a condition to exclude them from the query result.

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE id_image NOT IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Yeah this is something I am looking for. Can I pass those numbers as an array. I will do this by javascript looping through to check the src of the images, storing them in an array to pass to the php file. The php file should then use an sql statement something as you've proposed.